# Is there a quick way (a way) to do this integral

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y) = 2xy-y$ over the square $0-2$

$\int _0 ^2 \int _0 ^2 (\frac{2xy-y}{\sqrt{1+2x^2+2y^2-2x}} )dxdy$

My fallback is to write the square-root as (something to do with x)^2 + (some 'constant' with x), then factor the constant out to get (something to do with x over some root of that constant)^2 + 1

Then go all hyperbolic. Is there a short-cut, or trick I've not seen? It seems like a lot of room for error, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those "reverse chain rule" type questions. Remember, you're only integrating with respect to one variable at a time. So considering only one variable, can you see the derivative of what's inside the square root in the numerator (up to a constant)?

Comment: No, because the derivative should always be multiplying the function and multiplication takes place in the numerator. You could think about the square root in the denominator as raising the inside to the power of -1/2